# Binding DataColumn.Caption to DataGrid Header

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

My question is similar to [Why DataColumn.Caption doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267408/why-datacolumn-caption-doesnt-work), but for WPF. I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataTable` using an MVVM pattern. The `DataGrid` has `AutoGenerateColumns = true`. How do I bind the DataGridColumn header text to the `DataColumn.Caption` instead of `DataColumn.ColumnName`? I was hoping for a solution like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="MyDataTable" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataColumn.Caption}"> <!--this does not work-->
...
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue in the code behind.

```
private void dgResults_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.Header = tableResults.Columns[e.PropertyName].Caption;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind your `DataTable` to `DataGrid.ItemSource` you usually provide its `DefaultView` whose type is `DataView`. You can use its `Table` property to access columns on that view properly casting values.

```
private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.Header = ((sender as DataGrid).ItemsSource as DataView).Table.Columns[e.PropertyName].Caption;
}
```