# How can I set the column name in a datagridview to something more user friendly than the columns of the table?

Tags: c#, datagridview, caption

Below is the code I am using currently - trying to use Caption as the name to display in         datagridview:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn column = new DataColumn
{
    DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"),
    AllowDBNull = false,
    Caption = "Start Day",
    ColumnName = "startDay",
    DefaultValue = 0
};
dt.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: Column.Name or dgv.HeaderText ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why DataColumn.Caption doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267408/why-datacolumn-caption-doesnt-work)

Comment: Yes! Found the answer in that article. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can change the name of the column in the table in this way and by updating the DataSource of the DataGrid it will change the name.

`DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn
                {
                    DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"),
                    AllowDBNull = false,
                    Caption = "Start Day",
                    ColumnName = "startDay",
                    DefaultValue = 0
                };
                dt.Columns.Add(column);

                dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "MyNewColumnName";
                dt.Columns["MyNewColumnName"].ColumnName = "OtherName";`

Answer (score 0):

```
dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Title Goes Here.";
```

Repeat for each column and change the index